# use maven-assembly-plugin , but jar only contain dependency project's classes, no app project classes

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a **library project** which I declared as a `<dependency>` of my **App project**.

The **library project**'s pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.library</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyLib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>MyLib</name>
    ...
```

My **App project**'s pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>MyApp</name>

    <dependencies>
      <!--include library project as a dependency-->
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.library</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyLib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
       </dependency>
      ...
   </dependencies>
```

Since I need an jar which includes classes of my library project, so I declared also **maven-assembly-plugin** in my **App project**'s pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
          <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </configuration>
    <executions> 
        <execution> 
            <id>make-jar</id> 
            <phase>package</phase> 
            <goals> 
              <goal>assembly</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

The **assembly.xml** looks like this:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <includes>
                <!--inclucde classes from my library project-->
                <include>com.my.library:MyLib</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Ok, at this point, I run `mvn clean install` under my **App project**, under target/ directory, I got **MyApp-jar-with-dependencies.jar**.

But when I check the content of above jar, it **only** contains classes of my **library project** but **doesn't contain** my **App project**'s classes? WHY?

Comment: In the assembly.xml, shouldn't you include your app classes as well as the library classes? <include>com.my.app</include>???

Comment: @EngineerDollery , are you sure I should include in that way??? Or are you asking me a question? Well, I tried before I post my question, I got "Error adding file-set for com.my.app:MyApp to archive...".

Comment: It's a question. The question mark at the end sort-of implies that :)